# Al aplastar sobre una imagen esta se abra centralizada

Tags: javascript, html, css

Quiero que cuando aplaste sobre la imagen esta se abra en el centro de la página, ademas de que el fondo de atrás se oscurezca un poco al momento de hacer esto.

Sería de mucha ayuda que me den la solución, ando aprendiendo :c
Pd: Pongo la etiqueta de JavaScript porque quizás se necesite JavaScript para esto.

Comment: Recuerda que tu pregunta no debe parecer [un ticket para desarrollo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433): muestra lo que has intentado hasta el momento. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Es evidente que esta recién comenzando en esto, es nuestro deber como comunidad guiar a las personas, no hacerlas sentir mal. Favor un poco de empatía.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo buscar librerías que hagan algo similar a lo que buscas. Existen varias tales como [lightbox2](https://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) y [lightGallery](https://www.lightgalleryjs.com/demos/thumbnails/).

Si quieres aprender puedes o ver el código de algo similar puedes ver este articulo de [W3School - How to - LightBox](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_lightbox.asp)

Espero haber ayudado!